# Is gRPC not suited for small projects?

Tags: grpc

For the past 2 weeks I have been struggling to setup a simple backend that utilises gRPC and communicates with a mobile client.
Reading online about this technology it feels like it is the proper easy going solution for my needs.

- Bridging client/server communication written in multiple languages Java/Kotlin/Swift/Go.
- Backwards compatibility checks for the API realized with [buf](https://buf.build/)
- Efficient communication by transferring binary data and utilising HTTP2
- Support for both RPC and REST thanks to [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway)

However when I decided to go down the gRPC path I faced a ton of issues (highlights of the issues, not actual questions):

- How to share protobuf message definitions across clients and server?
- How to manage third party protobuf message dependencies?
- How to manage stub generation for projects using different build tools?
- How to secure the communication using SSL certificates? Also keep in mind that here I am talking about a `mobile client <--> server` communication and not `server <--> server` communication.
- How to buy a domain because SSL certificates are issued agains public domains in order to be trusted by Certificate Authorities?
- How to deploy a gRPC server as it turns out that there aren't any easy to use PaaS that support gRPC and HTTP2? Instead you either need to configure the infrastructure like load balancers and machines hosting the server by installing the appropriate certificates or just host everything on your own bear metal.
- How to manage all of the above in a cost effective way?

This is more of a frustration question.
Am I doing something wrong and misunderstanding how to use gRPC or is it simply too hard to setup for a small project that should run in production mod?

I feel like I wasted a ton of time without having made any progress.

Comment: Please do not post multiple questions in a single one

Comment: The questions 1 "Is gRPC an overhead for small projects" the rest are just highlights of all of the issues that one needs to go through in order to have a production ready setup.

Comment: Please share more details - what do you mean by "overhead"? Either you need it, or you don't

Comment: Did you read the question? I have listed 7 points that you need to overcome in order to start using gRPC. That is what I mean by overhead.